# Using php, how to select items from an array at an interval to give them an additional class

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of categories and subcategories. The number of both can vary depending on the site. The list of categories is generated using php and mySQL in accordance to whatever database.

What I would like to do is to split the categories into rows. Let's say I want 4 columns, then whatever the number of categories I have will be displayed into rows of 4 columns stacked above each other. The html and css in order to do this I already have it.

With the example above, each category div element will get a class of one_quarter, no problem there. I just need to be able to identify the first column of every row. i.e. the first, fifth the ninth etc... for those I need to give a class of first_column.

```
<div class="one_quarter firstcolumn">
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="one_quarter">
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="one_quarter">
    <h3>Category 3</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="one_quarter">
    <h3>Category 4</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
        <li>Subcategory</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm looking at [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and somewhat understand the concept but can't figure out in the example below (from the link) how to give the a, c and e an additional class.

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you will need two arrays One For categories, and other for sub

and same for loops, Main loop and sub loop insides it.

But while you are importing from MYSQL no need to have an array you can print directly

[you can find Sample here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all what's said below should be applied only if you cannot achieve the same goal via CSS means. It's a common trick in stacking layouts: you give some fixed width to a container, then set the corresponding width (in your case, 25% of the former) for each stacked 'card' - and apply `float: left` to it.

---

If `$categories` is an array (it seems so), you indeed can use [**array_chunk**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split it into array of, well, chunks - each chunk having 4 categories or less:

```
$row_categories = array_chunk($categories, 4);
```

... then output each row separately:

```
<?php foreach($row_categories as $row): ?>
  <?php foreach($row as $i => $cats): ?>
    <div class="one_quarter<?= $i === 0 ? ' first_column' : ''?>">
       <!-- some relevant HTML --> 
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But (as I assumed already) you output your categories within a `foreach` loop, right, it might be enough to add some simple `if` branching based on categories' index remainder:

```
<?php 
  $COLUMNS_IN_ROW = 4;
  foreach($categories as $i => $cat):
?>
<div class="one_quarter<?= $i % $COLUMNS_IN_ROW === 0 ? ' first_column' : ''?>">
  <!-- some relevant HTML -->    
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The first approach is the way to go if you need (or going to need) to add some more HTML in between the rows. But the second is obviously more simple.